# PHP/MYSQL calculate and suggest similarity between items (sets of array?)

Tags: php, mysql

I have items in my store db which all have multiple tags, along with colors, model and of course title and description...

I was thinking to calculate similarity by extracting an array of tags for each item eg [camping, sport, red, blue, ...] then comparing Item 1's array, with all the rest of the DB...

Problem is I have thousands of items...I wonder if this approach is ok or just stressful for mysql/php?

Comment: If the tags have a many-to-many relationship with your items, you can find items with the most tags in common using an SQL query.

Comment: @fubar I'd like to know how that is done.

Comment: @fubar yes i have separate table just for tags_id and item_id so what's the sQL? I also have SOLR search installed...if it helps

Comment: [Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556378/algorithm-that-searches-for-related-items-based-on-common-tags), [Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17370847/sql-query-to-determine-the-most-similar-goods-by-tags), [Example 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25188948/sorting-items-on-matching-tags-that-have-a-weight-in-mysql)